# React duplicate component getting displayed using layout

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I'm having trouble with React. I've read the documentation but I'm still confused as to what steps need to be taken.

I have created PrimaryLayout and using props children items is called. In the index file(Page) the PrimaryLayout is called and embedded card component.

However, in the output I am seeing duplicate components.

Appreciate your help.

**Please find below code**

**PrimaryLayout.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import Header from "../components/Header"
import FooterMessage from "../components/FooterMessage"

const PrimaryLayout = (props) => (
    <div>
    <Header/>
        <div className="container">
        <div className="row justify-content-md-center">
            <div className="col-xs-6">
                {props.children}
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    <FooterMessage/>
</div>
);
export default PrimaryLayout;
```

**Card Component**

```
import React from 'react'
import {Card, Button} from 'react-bootstrap'

const CardBox = (props) => (
    <div className ="p-3">
    <Card>
        <Card.Img variant="top" src="https://loremflickr.com/640/360" />
        <Card.Body>
            <Card.Title>{props.titleFirst}</Card.Title>
            <Card.Text>{props.description}</Card.Text>
            <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
        </Card.Body>
    </Card>
    <Card>
        <Card.Img variant="top" src="https://loremflickr.com/640/360" />
        <Card.Body>
            <Card.Title>{props.titleSecond}</Card.Title>
            <Card.Text>{props.description}</Card.Text>
            <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
        </Card.Body>
    </Card>
</div>
);

export default CardBox;
```

**Index.js**

```
import React from "react"
import CardBox from "../components/CardBox"
import PrimaryLayout from "../layouts/PrimaryLayout"
export default () => (
          <PrimaryLayout>
            <CardBox 
              titleFirst="This is my first post" 
              description = "We are writing something to be displayed in description"
            />
            <CardBox 
              titleSecond="This is my first post" 
              description = "We are writing something to be displayed in description"
            />
        </PrimaryLayout>  
)
```

Comment: You have added the `CardBox` component twice as child of the `PrimaryLayout` in the `index.js` file. How many instances of the `CardBox` do you see?

Comment: I am seeing 4 instances of card component in the final page. 
First component with titleFirst, Second component without title only description, third component with titleSecond and Fourth component with only description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, this has to do with the `CardBox` component. Right now you create 2 `Card` components within the `CardBox` component. This means that for every `CardBox` component you'll get 2 `Card` components. The first `Card` with `titleFirst` and the description, the second `Card` with `titleSecond` and the description.
If you change the `BoxCard` component to display the `Card` only ones like so:

```
const CardBox = (props) => (
    <div className ="p-3">
    <Card>
        <Card.Img variant="top" src="https://loremflickr.com/640/360" />
        <Card.Body>
            <Card.Title>{props.title}</Card.Title>
            <Card.Text>{props.description}</Card.Text>
            <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
        </Card.Body>
    </Card>
</div>
);
```

and let the index.js use it like so:

```
export default () => (
  <PrimaryLayout>
    <CardBox 
      title="This is my first post" 
      description = "We are writing something to be displayed in description"
    />
    <CardBox 
      title="This is my first post - second CardBox" 
      description = "We are writing something to be displayed in description"
    />
  </PrimaryLayout>  
);
```

Hope this is what you are looking for!

Comment: Thank you so much. I was able to fix the issue.

Comment: If you could mark this answer as correct it would help the community a lot :) This way people know the question has been answered ;)
You can mark it as correct on the left side of the answer